# Why does a batch file create unexpected icon on desktop?

Tags: batch-file, desktop

We run 2 batch files to swap IP addresses for the ethernet connection and copy an icon on the desktop so the user can see which "mode" they are in. There's a small problem. They create an empty icon (sometimes a blank page icon and sometimes a folder icon) on the desktop. I'm guessing it's a NULL.

Is there a way to remove the icon within the batch file?

**First Batch:**

```
@echo off
Net Session >Null 2>&1 || GoTo RunAdmin
del %userprofile%\desktop\TestingMode.ico
copy "c:\ded files\ReplicationMode.ico" %userprofile%\desktop

:: Configuration Variables ::
set connectionName="Ethernet 3"

netsh interface ip set address %connectionName% dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns %connectionName% dhcp
ie4uinit.exe -show

cls
echo YOU'RE NOW CONFIGURED FOR REPLICATION SERVICES.
TIMEOUT 5
EXIT

:RunAdmin
cls
echo.
echo. Please close this window and RIGHT Click and Choose 'Run as Administrator'
echo.
timeout /t -1 
GOTO Stop
```

**Second Batch:**

```
@echo off
Net Session >Null 2>&1 || GoTo RunAdmin
del %userprofile%\desktop\ReplicationMode.ico
copy "c:\DED files\TestingMode.ico" %userprofile%\desktop

:: Configuration Variables ::
set connectionName="Ethernet 3"
set staticIP=192.168.1.50
set subnetMask=255.255.255.0
set defaultGateway=192.168.1.1

netsh interface ip set address %connectionName% static %staticIP% %subnetMask% %defaultGateway% 1
ie4uinit.exe -show

cls
echo YOU'RE NOW CONFIGURED FOR TESTING SERVICES.
TIMEOUT 5
EXIT
```

Comment: You should be using **`Nul`** not **`Null`**!

Comment: Thanks Compo.  I'll try it.  Still learning programming language.  What's the difference?

Comment: The former will output to the `NUL` device, the latter to a file named `Null`

Comment: The icons are still being created.  I've narrowed down the cause to the first command.  Any ideas how to stop or remove the icons?